# What is the meaning of "www-ssl" in the URL https://www-ssl.intel.com/?

Tags: tls, web-browser, protocols

While browsing INTEL website I came across the following link

`https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/in/en/data-center/new-center-of-possibility.html?cid=sem63p45119g-c&intel_term=intel%20distribution%20of%20hadoop&gclid=CN7HpsX5xcYCFUgmjgod9kQEPA`

What is "www-ssl"?

Few times while browsing IBM website I have come across "ww3.xyz.ibm.com",

What is "ww3"?

I did not find anything on GOOGLING

Comment: Try GOOGLING the term `subdomain`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are simply Subdomains created by the website owner.

`ww3` is often used to share load (ww1,ww2,ww3) on their servers.
In you example it seems intel created `www-ssl` subdomain to separate normal http traffic and https traffic on subdomain level.

If you want more information why somebody is doing this, just ask google or the website owner